# Magento Error Loggin

Tags: xml, magento

I an new to Magento, hence the mind-space of "WHY ?".

I am working my way around Modules and Templates for now. I was able to create one module, but the test one just does not seem to work.

I created the module.xml and etc/config.xml. The module shows up in the advance listing. Although when I try loading the page index.php/module/index/action (index.php/weblog/index/testModel). It just says "404 Whoops, our bad...".

I know I have done something wrong, although I do not have a log where I can look into to know whats going on.

How am I to start debugging this ?

Module/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <weblog>
           <use>standard</use>
           <args>
            <module>Alanstormdotcom_Weblog</module>
            <frontName>weblog</frontName>
           </args>
        </weblog>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

Comment: Can you post your modules config.xml please :)

Comment: Is that your entire config.xml ?

Comment: Ah, figured it out. I missed the <modules> sectio in my config ! Thanks. And yes, that is all it was :) Wish Magento would tell me this !

Answer (score 1):

I think your missing some extra xml in your config file that is required:

It should look like this at the very least:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Alanstormdotcom_Weblog>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Alanstormdotcom_Weblog>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <weblog>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Alanstormdotcom_Weblog</module>
                    <frontName>weblog</frontName>
                </args>
            </weblog>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

I missed the < modules > section in my config.xml.

note: Leaving this post and not closing it, it might help someone sometime understand magento configs better.

Comment: Thats not how stack overflow works :) - If someone gives you help/correct answer, then you should upvote and accept the answer.  This helps people identify useful solutions in the future